# How to export into a file all records from the tables of a database ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have a lot of records that are stored into multiple tables in a database , for example `ContosoUniversity` .

I want to export all the records into a file , and restore it any time that I want .

Any idea how to do that in SQL SERVER 2012 ?

Please note that I don't want the code of creating the DB , meaning I don't want this :

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [ContosoUniversity]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [ContosoUniversity]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'School', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\School.mdf' , SIZE = 3328KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'School_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\School_log.ldf' , SIZE = 3136KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [ContosoUniversity].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'ContosoUniversity', N'ON'
GO
USE [ContosoUniversity]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeleteOfficeAssignment]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOfficeAssignment]
        @InstructorID int
        AS
        DELETE FROM OfficeAssignment
        WHERE InstructorID=@InstructorID;

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeletePerson]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeletePerson]
        @PersonID int
        AS
        DELETE FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @PersonID;

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetCourses]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCourses] 
            AS
            SELECT CourseID, Title, Credits, DepartmentID FROM dbo.Course
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetDepartmentName]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDepartmentName]
      @ID int,
      @Name nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
      AS
      SELECT @Name = Name FROM Department
      WHERE DepartmentID = @ID

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetStudentGrades]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentGrades]
            @StudentID int
            AS
            SELECT EnrollmentID, Grade, CourseID, StudentID FROM dbo.StudentGrade
            WHERE StudentID = @StudentID

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertInstructor]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertInstructor] 
            @LastName nvarchar(50), 
        @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
        @HireDate datetime 
        AS
        INSERT INTO dbo.Person (LastName,  
                    FirstName,  
                    HireDate) 
        VALUES (@LastName,  
            @FirstName,  
            @HireDate); 
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewPersonID;
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertOfficeAssignment]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOfficeAssignment]
        @InstructorID int,
        @Location nvarchar(50)
        AS
        INSERT INTO dbo.OfficeAssignment (InstructorID, Location)
        VALUES (@InstructorID, @Location);
        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Timestamp] FROM OfficeAssignment 
                WHERE InstructorID=@InstructorID;
        END

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertPerson]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPerson]
        @LastName nvarchar(50),
        @FirstName nvarchar(50),
        @HireDate datetime,
        @EnrollmentDate datetime
        AS
        INSERT INTO dbo.Person (LastName, 
                    FirstName, 
                    HireDate, 
                    EnrollmentDate)
        VALUES (@LastName, 
            @FirstName, 
            @HireDate, 
            @EnrollmentDate);
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewPersonID;

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertStudent]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertStudent] 
        @LastName nvarchar(50), 
        @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
        @EnrollmentDate datetime 
        AS
        INSERT INTO dbo.Person (LastName,  
                    FirstName,  
                    EnrollmentDate) 
        VALUES (@LastName,  
            @FirstName,  
            @EnrollmentDate); 
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewPersonID;
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateInstructor]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateInstructor] 
        @PersonID int, 
        @LastName nvarchar(50), 
        @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
        @HireDate datetime 
        AS
        UPDATE Person SET LastName=@LastName,  
                FirstName=@FirstName, 
                HireDate=@HireDate 
        WHERE PersonID=@PersonID;
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateOfficeAssignment]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateOfficeAssignment]
        @InstructorID int,
        @Location nvarchar(50),
        @OrigTimestamp timestamp
        AS
        UPDATE OfficeAssignment SET Location=@Location 
        WHERE InstructorID=@InstructorID AND [Timestamp]=@OrigTimestamp;
        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Timestamp] FROM OfficeAssignment 
                WHERE InstructorID=@InstructorID;
        END

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdatePerson]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePerson]
        @PersonID int,
        @LastName nvarchar(50),
        @FirstName nvarchar(50),
        @HireDate datetime,
        @EnrollmentDate datetime
        AS
        UPDATE Person SET LastName=@LastName, 
                FirstName=@FirstName,
                HireDate=@HireDate,
                EnrollmentDate=@EnrollmentDate
        WHERE PersonID=@PersonID;

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateStudent]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStudent] 
        @PersonID int, 
        @LastName nvarchar(50), 
        @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
        @EnrollmentDate datetime 
        AS
        UPDATE Person SET LastName=@LastName,  
                FirstName=@FirstName, 
                EnrollmentDate=@EnrollmentDate 
        WHERE PersonID=@PersonID;
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Course]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Credits] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School.Course] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CourseInstructor]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseInstructor](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CourseInstructor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC,
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Department]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Budget] [money] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Administrator] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DepartmentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OfficeAssignment]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OfficeAssignment](
    [InstructorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OfficeAssignment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstructorID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OnlineCourse]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OnlineCourse](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OnlineCourse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OnsiteCourse]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OnsiteCourse](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Days] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OnsiteCourse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Person]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EnrollmentDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School.Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StudentGrade]    Script Date: 5/18/2014 7:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentGrade](
    [EnrollmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Grade] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentGrade] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EnrollmentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_Department] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([DepartmentID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_Department]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseInstructor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseInstructor_Course] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseInstructor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseInstructor_Course]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseInstructor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseInstructor_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseInstructor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseInstructor_Person]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OfficeAssignment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OfficeAssignment_Person] FOREIGN KEY([InstructorID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OfficeAssignment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OfficeAssignment_Person]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OnlineCourse]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OnlineCourse_Course] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OnlineCourse] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OnlineCourse_Course]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OnsiteCourse]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OnsiteCourse_Course] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OnsiteCourse] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OnsiteCourse_Course]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentGrade]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentGrade_Course] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentGrade] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentGrade_Course]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentGrade]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentGrade_Student] FOREIGN KEY([StudentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentGrade] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentGrade_Student]
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [ContosoUniversity] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

What I want are the records in those tables . Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two simple option,

1. Use Database Scripting.
2. Use Export/Import Wizard.

[image]

**Where to find Advance Scripting options**

[image]

**To select data when generating scripts**

[image]

Comment: Generate scripts doesn't grab the RECORDS , only creates the statements . I've just tried it ... no records were restored , only the tables .

Comment: You have the option of including data look again.

Comment: @James have a look this option is in `Advance Scripting Options` when configuring your script wizard.

Comment: Can you please direct me where this option is available ? I searched the entire options under `Generate Scripts` in SQL SERVER 2012 SP1 , but no option for including data is visible .

Comment: Have a look I have updated my answer.